# Retagging [vector] to [stdvector]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

We currently have [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) and [stdvector](/questions/tagged/stdvector). From the questions, they both deal with C++'s `std::vector`. However, vector also describes a non-one-dimensional movement in physics.

Yes, we aren't a math site. There's [physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [mo](https://mathoverflow.net/) for that. But I still think we shouldn't be using [vector](/questions/tagged/vector)

---

This is *not* a tag synonym request, but a *retag* request. I guarantee you there is or will be a programming question involving mathematical vectors.

Comment: There are a lot of questions there...that's a lot to go through.  Probably easier to try to pick out the much smaller subset that aren't referring to std vector so that all that's left is the C++ code, then do an automated mass copy.

Comment: @Servy Never thought of that. Can you make that an answer?

Comment: No, as I'm not sure if that's appropriate in this case or not.  It's just an idea.

Comment: Tags can be merged; it's the equivalent of a bulk retag.  Are we sure that [vector] isn't being used in some questions as a more generic tag than std::vector?

Comment: @Servy if that's what you think should happen, that's a valid reason for an answering. Then we vote :)

Comment: @RobertHarvery did you read my last paragraph about that? We have a tag for [tag:sudoku]. That's a tag referencing the problem people are trying to solve. If I was a new user solving a problem involving math vectors, I might just tag it [tag:vector] also.

Comment: C++ is not the only language to have vector classes/structs in their language/base class libraries, Java for one.

Answer (score 8):

No, don't merge a generic tag (7666 questions have it) with a specific one (608).

The generic tag is used for all kinds of vectors currently, so retagging it would cause a ton of trouble, as not all questions currently tagged [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) are about [stdvector](/questions/tagged/stdvector).

Unless you're planning on manually going through almost eight thousand questions to find out which of them are not about [stdvector](/questions/tagged/stdvector) and correctly retagging the rest, I don't see how you could harmlessly merge them.

Comment: Want to argue about the rest of the ambiguously tagged questions? :) Seriously, ensuring that a tag is used appropriately takes quite some time, especially from a person who is not in position to decide that due to lack of experience in a given area. Sure, math vectors and C++ are not the best example, but good luck convincing people to spend their time on 20 questions they may not know much about.